# Getting the "Open in..." overlay in iOS via SDK

Tags: iphone, uidocumentinteraction

I have an iOS app which offers the opportunity to open documents in other applications via UIDocumentInteractionController. Neither `presentOpenInMenuFromRect` nor `presentOpenInMenuFromBarButtonItem` does the Safari-style overlay menu of "Open in..." "Open in iBooks" that you get when viewing a PDF (for instance) and those appear to be the only ways to ask for a menu. My "Open In" menu does work, it's just not the UI experience I am trying to offer. Is this functionality in a private framework or am I missing something more obvious?

Edit: I suspect it's a toolbar with 2 buttons, and I just can't have it unless I build one myself, having looked harder. Still looking for confirmation or denial.

Comment: that's exactly the opposite, being a target of it. in this case i want to be (and am) a source, the issue is not that i can't do it, it's that it's not the UI experience i am trying to have. i want the small overlay bar with the buttons, rather than the behavior i get with ...FromRect or ...FromBarButtonItem (the same large buttons in either case)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it's denial... It's not possible under the official SDK to:

- Get a list of applications that open a certain file.
- Open a certain file on a certain application (other than the URL schemes registered).