# Cocoa Touch get list of apps that open a certain file (mime)

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have several files that I am displaying via UIWebView. I want to provide the user possible alternative apps to view the files in. How can I get a list of these apps and how can I open these apps with the files programmatically?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like I said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9607581/366492):

It's **not possible** under the official SDK to:

- Get a list of applications that open a certain file.
- Open a certain file on a certain application (other than the URL schemes registered).